# Python izip memory error with izip.count()

Tags: python, out-of-memory, python-itertools, izip

I ran the following code:

```
import itertools
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in itertools.izip([x for x in my_list], [y for y in itertools.count()]):
        print i
```

Based on the [documentation for izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), I expected it to return a series of tuples, ending when `my_list` ran out: (a,0) (b,1) (c,2) (d,3) (e,4)

Instead, I get the memory error copied below. It seems the `itertools.count()` function is returning infinite data, rather than being limited to the 5 records in `my_list`?

```
line 50, in main
    for i in itertools.izip([x for x in range(10)], [y for y in itertools.count()]): MemoryError
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) was designed to never stop counting.  That is why it returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#iterator), which produces items on demand rather than all at once.

However, this part of your code:

```
[y for y in itertools.count()]
```

effectively tells Python to place the infinite amount of numbers produced by `itertools.count` into a single list.  Thus, a `MemoryError` is raised because this operation immediately consumes all available memory.

---

You can fix your problem by simply removing the list comprehension<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> for i in itertools.izip(my_list, itertools.count()):
...     print i
...
('a', 0)
('b', 1)
('c', 2)
('d', 3)
('e', 4)
>>>
```

With this change, `itertools.izip` will iterate over the iterator returned by `itertools.count()`, which will now only produce as many numbers as are needed.

---

<sup>1</sup>I removed your other list comprehension too because it is unnecessary:  `my_list` is already iterable because it is a list.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this?

```
for a,b in enumerate(my_list):
    print (b, a)
```